# Setting default value to Null in mongoengine Model python

Tags: python-3.x, pymongo, mongoengine

```
from pymodm import connect, fields, MongoModel, EmbeddedMongoModel
from pymongo import IndexModel, ASCENDING, TEXT,client_session
import arrow
from sqlalchemy.log import echo_property
from sqlalchemy.orm import session, sessionmaker
# from .models import *
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings
import arrow
from time import sleep
from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import null

from sqlalchemy.sql.schema import PrimaryKeyConstraint


def db_connect():
    """
    Performs database connection using database settings from settings.py.
    Returns sqlalchemy engine instance
    """
    engine = connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/abcd")
    return engine

now = arrow.get(arrow.now('America/New_York')).datetime

class Live_pr(MongoModel):
    uni_identifier = fields.CharField(required=True,primary_key=True)
    symbol = fields.ListField(required=True)
    #...........
    #..........
    price_dollar = fields.FloatField(blank=True, null=True, default=None) #I want set default Null for this field
    is_new = fields.IntegerField(default=1)
    scrape_timestamp = fields.DateTimeField(default=now)

    class Meta:
        cascade = True

db_connect()

#.....
#scrapy pipeline code
#....

def process_item(self, item, spider):
    prs = Live_pr()

    prs.uni_identifier = item["uni_identifier"]
    prs.symbol = item["symbols"]
    if item["price"]:
        prs.price_dollar = item["price"]
    prs.save()
```

I just want to know if there is a way to set default as Null in mongoengine model."default=None" does not work.It just drops the entire field. And setting "null=true" throws this type error:

> File
> "/home/*******/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymodm/fields.py",
> line 89, in **init**
> super(CharField, self).**init**(verbose_name=verbose_name,  TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'null'

Answer (score 1):

**You can set default like this:**

```
field2 = fields.CharField(blank=True, null=True, default=None)
```

Comment: Hmm let me try it

Comment: I just update the answer. could you please try this?

Comment: Nope same error. I am suddenly starting to hate python

Comment: its throwing error on just passing null parameter for some reason

Comment: could you please try with `default=""`? If it's worked then we can discuss frontend issue later

Comment: Didn't Work.Its a float type field. Its one of most important fields.I am checking whether its null or not and a lot of API flow depends on that decision. And for some reason I have to run a scrapy spider to insert in that collection.

Comment: which filed you are talking about? I can't see any float field in your provided code. if possible then share the full code.

Comment: Ok updated the code a bit. Should be enough to give you a basic idea. Entire code is too long and basically redundant for this use case.

Comment: If mongoengine can set null I can change engine from pymodm to mongoengine

Comment: Sabil  can work with it. Its dropping field. guess i will just have to use "if (variable1)"
Wanted to avoid frontend refactoring.

Comment: Yes, You can set null in DB and check in frontend for your desired result. :)

Comment: U have any suggestions abt a good mongo ODM for python? Except mongoengine? Something similar to moongose??

Comment: You can try **PyMongo** , **μMongo** or **Ming**. Hope one of this will work for you